# Eliminar un objeto dentro de un array en MongoDB

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Tengo esta estructura en mi colección

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta para poder eliminar ese objeto que dice producto1, estaba tratando de hacerlo primero con el nombre, que era producto1, luego trate de hacerlo con el ID pero ninguno de los dos me dio solución, actualmente tengo este codigo:

```
const productoPorBorrar = arrayProductos[0];
    const productosToEliminar = await inventarioModel.updateOne(
      {
        _id: inventario._id,
      },
      {
        $pull: {
          productos: {
            productoPorBorrar: { id: codigoProducto },
          },
        },
      }
    );
```

Aclaro, el `productoPorBorrar` contiene un array en su posicion 0, mejor dicho, contiene el string 'producto1', y pues el codigoProducto, es el req.body que recibo de la petición.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te propongo la siguiente alternativa para lograr el objetivo: *eliminar un elemento de una lista dentro de un documento en una colección en MongoDB*.

Puedes recuperar el elemento al que hace referencia `productoPorBorrar` y usar el campo `id` que recibes en la solicitud.

**Usando [`findById()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) seguido de [`save()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-save):**

Podrías obtener una copia del documento, modificar el mismo y luego salvarlo con los cambios realizados.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const productoPorBorrar = arrayProductos[0]; // esto es 'producto1'
const document = await inventarioModel.findById({_id: inventario._id});
let itemToRemove = document.productos.find(producto => producto[productoPorBorrar].id === codigoProducto);
if(itemToRemove) {
  document.productos.pull(itemToRemove);
  savedDocument = await document.save();
} else {
  // acciones en caso de que no se encuentre el elemento a eliminar
}
```

Como se aprecia en el código, he utilizado el método [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find) del tipo `Array` de Javascript, para encontrar el elemento que deseo eliminar. Si el elemento se encuentra en la lista, procedo a eliminarlo y luego salvar el documento.

El problema particular con el tipo de elementos almacenados en tu lista de productos, es que usas una clave cuyo nombre varía.

Tienes un objeto con la siguiente estructura:

```js
{
  <nombre_de_producto>: { 
    id: <valor>,
    cantidad: <valor>
  }
}
```

Eso hace difícil el manejo de la información ya que por cada producto tendrás en tu lista un elemento con un nombre de clave diferente. Mi propuesta es que cambies el formato del elemento a algo parecido a esto:

```js
{
  id: <valor>,
  nombre: <nombre_de_producto>,
  cantidad: <valor>
}
```

Este elemento siempre contiene 3 campos: `id`, `nombre`, `cantidad`. De esta forma es mucho más fácil de manejar y podrías usar el comando [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/index.html) tal como lo estabas intentando.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias, he decido cambiar el formato a como lo recomendaste, es más fácil manejarlo así y logre hacer el pull, gracias.